# get notified when windows firewall rule list get modified

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

Windows firewall ownership can be taken by using interfaces like `INetFwProduct`, `INetFwProducts`. My requirement is, my program should get notified when any program adds exception rule in windows firewall rule list.

How to achieve this?

Are there any callback functions available?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will find that people are much more willing to help someone asking "I want to do X, so I tried Y, but then Z went wrong. How do I fix this problem?" rather than "I want to do X, please tell me what to do".

Comment: Following are my tryouts:
1. I am able to register third party firewall and take ownership of windows firewall.
2. I can enumerate windows firewall exception rules.
3. I can add any rule in outbound exception list.
All this is achived via interfaces like INetFwProduct, INetFwProducts, INetFwPolicy2, INetFwRules, INetFwRule, etc

Now my requirement is, if any program adds such rule in inbound/outbound exception list my program should get notification.
I could not find APIs to do so hence posted a question.

Comment: @Mrunal Did you solve the problem ?